# VBA Finding Last Row with Value in Table Column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have a table with several items in it. These items all have a code, and they will repeat themselves, row by row. I mean to single out the last 'repetition' of a item in a table, i need to have the address or row reference, something i can work with so i can later bring it to a new table, where i'll make a monthly overview of the current status of our items, present in the first table. 
And I've almost got it, the following code:

```
'codTeste is a integer in this example
codTeste = Range("AE:AE").Find(what:="REST0300", after:=Range("AE1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Does work but isn't there a way like so:

```
codTeste = Range(tblDesc.DataBodyRange.Address).Find(what:="REST0300", after:=Range(TheFirstCellOfTheRelevantColumnDataBodyRange), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'If I do this it'll throw me a mismatch error
```

the point would be to make it more dynamic, so as to not restrict the find method to a very specific range parameter...

Comment: if you record a macro will Finding it manually, you can find the correct syntax and adjust the code where necessary.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, hey Scott; I haven't got much experience in recording macros to be honest although I understand the jist of what you're suggesting...How would I manually find it whilst recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dim inCol as integer

inCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="Product Code", After:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

I can't comment, but this will find the column number given the name @steps

Comment: I was looking for a "direct reference kind of way" but this is a great alternative, thank you! 

 Just one small correction, I was getting off values with xlPrevious, 
I changed it to xlNext and it provided me with the proper column index, at least in my current workbook.

So, you and Tim are basically the answer, :p thank you guys.

Comment: Glad we could help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim trng As Range, f As Range, inCol As Long
Set trng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange

useCol = 2

Set f = trng.Columns(inCol).Find(what:="77", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
        searchdirection:=xlPrevious, after:=trng.Columns(inCol).Cells(1))

If Not f Is Nothing Then Debug.Print f.Row
```

Comment: It works great but instead of numbering the column (inCol) is there a way of just putting the name of the column i'm looking for there? I'm afraid if I were to add a number into it the initial problem would remain;

In my example that would be "Product Code".  I'd like to reference that column not by number but by it's name. This would make it more dynamic (or so I believe, do correct me if I'm wrong)